# how to change the color of the resulting foreground to white color after grabcut algorithm?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

This is the following code for grabcut algorithm. I want to get the resulting forground in white color instead of the original color. Here is the output obtained from the following code from the [link](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_grabcut/py_grabcut.html).

[image]

```
import numpy as np

import cv2
from matplotlib
import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg')
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)
bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
rect = (50,50,450,290)
cv2.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]
plt.imshow(img),plt.colorbar(),plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

After this line `cv2.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)`, you get a single channel mask with 4 distinct values namely:

> - GC_FGD = 0
> - GC_BGD = 1
> - GC_PR_FGD = 2
> - GC_PR_BGD = 3.

To get a binary mask out of this mask you need to replace `GC_FGD = 0` and `GC_PR_FGD = 2` with values `255`, which can be done as:

```
mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0), 0, 255).astype('uint8')
```

Skip the multiply step and you have your binary mask stored in mask2.